# jQuery selector: this.parent, is there such a thing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a lot of div boxes with nested div `.title`s, with a button inside. Is there a way in jQuery to select the parent of the button?

Something like:

```
$("#button").click(function(){       
       $("this.parent").css({'border-bottom' : 'none'});
       });
```

Or am I going to have to rename all of my title classes to unique classes?

Comment: Not a selector, but a method. Selectors always goes upwards in the tree, not downward.

Comment: Method is what I meant.. I swear... Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a whirl (inside an event handler for that button):

```
$(this).parent().css({'border-bottom' : 'none'});
```

Comment: @GlenCrawford you got extra " in there

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Still learning jQuery, best way to do it us by doing!

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks break a leg, +1 Glen

Comment: Thanks :) one day I'll answer a jQuery question :P

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
$("#button").click(function(){       
       $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom' : 'none'});
       });
```

or    `$(this).parent("div").css({'border-bottom' : 'none'});`

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(function(){
  $("div.title a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");
    return false;
  });
});
```